# set cameraOverlayView with xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I created a simple xib file with a UIView and a UILabel in the middle of the view.  I then set the owner of the xib to be the ViewController that will be using it.  I created an outlet from the UIView to my ViewController and did the following:

```
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = self.cameraOverlay;
```

The problem I am having is that it is not appearing when I open the camera.  If I create the UIView programmatically it works, but it doesn't seem to work if I use a xib file.

Below is the code where I set the overlay, and camera:

```
- (IBAction)takeVideo:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    NSArray *availableTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    if ([availableTypes containsObject:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        [imagePicker setMediaTypes:@[(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]];
    } 
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = self.cameraOverlay;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The camerOverlay is (strong, nonatomic)

Comment: Have you declared the cameraOverlay outlet as a weak property?

Comment: No i have declared it as (strong, nonatomic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you loaded the nib in code?

`self.cameraOverlay = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourNibNameHere" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];`

Place this in your `viewDidLoad` method.